# Websphere 6.1 to 7 how to update ibm-web-bnd.xmi to ibm-web-bnd.xml

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, websphere-7

In Websphere 6 ibm-web-bnd.xmi file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" 
     xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
     xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" 
     xmi:id="WebAppBinding_1294064796872"
     virtualHostName="default_host">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
  <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1294083767913" jndiName="jdbc/ABC_DEFG">
    <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ResourceRef_1294083767913"/>
  </resRefBindings>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

I would like to upgrade to the Websphere 7 and use the default ibm-web-bnd.XML file, but I am not sure how to update it...could someone provide some ideas. THANKS

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
     version="1.0">

     <virtual-host name="default_host" />

<!--WHAT TO PUT HERE FOR jdbc/ABC_DEFG -->

    </web-bnd>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to find the corresponding ResourceRef_1294083767913 stanza in web.xml.  It should be in this format:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/myResRef</res-ref-name>
  ...
</resource-ref>
```

In that case, you would add this element to ibm-web-bnd.xml:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/myResRef" binding-name="jdbc/ABC_DEFG"/>
```

The InfoCenter topic, [EJB 3.0 application bindings overview](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html), actually explains the XML bindings format for ibm-ejb-jar.xml, ibm-web-bnd.xml, and ibm-application-client-bnd.xml.