# Websphere 6.1 to 8.5 how to update ibm-web-bnd.xmi to ibm-web-bnd.xml Remote EJB

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-6.1

In Websphere 6 ibm-web-bnd.xmi file I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd:WebAppBinding
  xmi:version="2.0"
  xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"
  xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi"
  xmi:id="WebAppBinding"
  virtualHostName="default_host">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ABCWebId"/>

    <ejbRefBindings xmi:id="ABCEJBBinding" jndiName="ejb/ABC">
       <bindingEjbRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ABCProcessEJBId"/>
    </ejbRefBindings>

</com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

So In Websphere 8.5 ibm-web-bnd.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd 
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

    <ejb-ref name="ejb/ABC"  binding-name="ejb/ABC"/>   

</web-bnd>
```

In websphere 6.1 and 8.5 web.xml I have

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>defaultEJBServer</param-name>
      <param-value>
         iiop://10.123.120.6:2816,http://10.123.120.6:9087/EJB-Servlet/classDispatcher
      </param-value>
</init-param>

<ejb-ref id="ABCProcessEJBId">      
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/ABC</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <home>com.ejb.process.ProcessHome</home>
    <remote>com.ejb.process.ProcessRemote</remote>
    <ejb-link>EJB-Client.jar#Process</ejb-link>     
</ejb-ref>
```

According to this post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628915/websphere-6-1-to-7-how-to-update-ibm-web-bnd-xmi-to-ibm-web-bnd-xml?answertab=active#tab-top)

It should work, the only diference is I´m using **ejb-ref** instead **resource-ref.**

The normal log error is:

```
[17/11/16 11:16:56:656 CST] 0000008b SystemOut     O - Unexpected naming 

exception while retrieving remote class for "ejb/ABC".
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4563)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1821)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.getRemoteClass(EJBLocator.java:199)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.locateEJB(EJBLocator.java:291)
    at com.bsd.biz.catalog.SimpleCatalogBiz.getDisposicionList(SimpleCatalogBiz.java:289)
    at com.service.impl.CompraServiceImpl.getDisposicion(CompraServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.web.controller.CompraController.Datos(CompraController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2473)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1253)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4623)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4618)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4617)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init>(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5229)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2160)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2957)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2953)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2951)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1817)
    ... 58 more
[17/11/16 11:16:56:658 CST] 0000008b SystemOut     O - Unable to close context: javax.naming.InitialContext@335399f2
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4563)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1821)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.getHomeClass(EJBLocator.java:179)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.locateEJB(EJBLocator.java:292)
    at com.bsd.funds.biz.catalog.SimpleCatalogBiz.getDisposicionList(SimpleCatalogBiz.java:289)
    at com.service.impl.CompraServiceImpl.getDisposicion(CompraServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.web.controller.CompraController.Datos(CompraController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
```

Full stack trace is:

```
[17/11/16 14:06:19:298 CST] 00000092 CNContextImpl 3   lookupExt
                             javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: 

LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
[17/11/16 14:06:19:298 CST] 00000092 CNContextImpl >  getNameInNamespace Entry
[17/11/16 14:06:19:298 CST] 00000092 CNContextImpl <  getNameInNamespace Exit
                                 LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1
[17/11/16 14:06:19:298 CST] 00000092 Helpers       3   jndiNamingException
                                 com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl
                                 lookupExt
                                 LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1
                                 stub/classes
                                 ""
                                 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4563)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1821)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.getRemoteClass(EJBLocator.java:199)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.locateEJB(EJBLocator.java:291)
    at com.bsd.funds.biz.catalog.SimpleCatalogBiz.getInvestmentFundDisposicionList(SimpleCatalogBiz.java:289)
    at com.afirme.afirmenet.service.impl.inversiones.FondoInversionCompraServiceImpl.getDisposicionInversion(FondoInversionCompraServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.afirme.afirmenet.web.controller.inversiones.FondoInversionCompraController.datosInversion(FondoInversionCompraController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2473)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1253)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4623)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4618)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4617)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init>(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5229)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2160)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2957)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2953)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2951)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1817)
    ... 58 more

[17/11/16 14:06:19:298 CST] 00000092 CNContextImpl <  lookupExt Exit
                                 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4563)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1821)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.getRemoteClass(EJBLocator.java:199)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.locateEJB(EJBLocator.java:291)
    at com.bsd.funds.biz.catalog.SimpleCatalogBiz.getInvestmentFundDisposicionList(SimpleCatalogBiz.java:289)
    at com.afirme.afirmenet.service.impl.inversiones.FondoInversionCompraServiceImpl.getDisposicionInversion(FondoInversionCompraServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.afirme.afirmenet.web.controller.inversiones.FondoInversionCompraController.datosInversion(FondoInversionCompraController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.handleNameNotFound(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:2473)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipcos.WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.getNextWsnOptimizedNamingContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImpl.java:1253)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4623)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$3.run(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4618)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.getTargetContext(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:4617)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase$LeafOperationData.<init>(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:5229)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.cosbase.WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.resolve_complete_info(WsnOptimizedNamingImplBase.java:2160)
    at com.ibm.WsnOptimizedNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve_complete_info(_NamingContextStub.java:538)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2957)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl$2.run(CNContextImpl.java:2953)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.retry(CommonHelpers.java:801)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.cosResolve(CNContextImpl.java:2951)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1817)
    ... 58 more

[17/11/16 14:06:19:299 CST] 00000092 CNContextImpl <  lookup Exit
                                 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
[17/11/16 14:06:19:302 CST] 00000092 SystemOut     O   - Unexpected naming exception while retrieving remote class for "ejb/ABC".
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: LAP4ADM001Node02Cell/nodes/LAP4ADM001Node02/servers/server1, name: stub/classes: First component in name stub/classes not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.mapNotFoundException(CNContextImpl.java:4563)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1821)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.doLookup(CNContextImpl.java:1776)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1433)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.getRemoteClass(EJBLocator.java:199)
    at com.bsd.ejb.EJBLocator.locateEJB(EJBLocator.java:291)
    at com.bsd.funds.biz.catalog.SimpleCatalogBiz.getDisposicionList(SimpleCatalogBiz.java:289)
    at com.service.impl.CompraServiceImpl.getDisposicionInversion(CompraServiceImpl.java:107)
    at com.web.controller.CompraController.datosInversion(CompraController.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
```

Comment: Can you supply the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: And for JNDI problems you can enable trace Naming=all as described here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143296 under "Collecting data manually"

Comment: I have updated my cuestion with the full stack trace and I going to try "Collecting data manually" following the page recommended.

Comment: I edited again with the real full stack trace. Strange but appears a error on the JNDI "stub/classes" and my JNDI is "ejb/ABC".

Comment: The `EJBLocator.getRemoteClass` is almost certainly doing `lookup("stub/classes")`.  What is that method doing?  Your question starts with a discussion of binding files, but that would only be relevant if your code is doing `lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/ABC")`, which does not seem to be the case.  (Perhaps your `getInvestmentFundDisposicionList` method is calling `lookupEJB("ejb/ABC")`, but it appears that method is doing something different before WebSphere has a chance to process it.)

Comment: @AlexandrePolozoff thank you for the full stack trace tip I noticed my real error.

Comment: @BrettKail thank you for your tip, I deleted my file ibm-web-bnd.xml because is not necessary. My application didn´t work because the inicialization of `stub/classes` was located in a servlet without the line `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` I added that line and some other JAR libraries and now everything is working perfectly :D

Comment: @DanielGalindo I would strongly recommend not adding your bindings in JNDI.  That creates awkward dependencies.